# Include signature in emails

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Based off several resources, I have the following Excel VBA code to send an email from Outlook:

```vb
Sub SendEmail()
Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object

Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)

sig = msg.HtmlBody
                   
msg.To = "fake@fake.com"
msg.Subject = "Subject Line!"
msg.HtmlBody = "<p>Body</p>" & sig
msg.Send
End Sub
```

However, my email signature is not being added to the end of the email body.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209091/add-signature-to-outlook-email-with-python-using-win32com

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the mail item to get the signature added:

```
Sub SendEmail()
  Dim OA As Object
  Dim msg As Object

  Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
  sig = msg.HtmlBody

  msg.To = "fake@fake.com"
  msg.Subject = "Subject Line!"
  msg.HtmlBody = "<p>Body</p>" & sig

  msg.Display()

  msg.Send
End Sub
```

Also, you must set a well-formed HTML markup to the `HTMLBody` property. That means you have to find the starting `<body>` tag and insert your text there right after it.

Comment: Saving an item does not add a signature. Only `MailItem.Display` does.