# Set signature in outlook e-mail body C++

Tags: c++, outlook, tlb

I have a little problem with my outlook interface.

I'm using `<outlook\msoutl.tlh>` to create and fill an e-mail item automatically.

But now I want to display my signature too.

I noticed that if I don't set the mail body, the signature is added automatically. But as soon as I want to set the mail body, the signature is not shown. It seems that it will be overwritten. So I tried the following :

```
string standardText = "Hello Outlook"
string signature = IMailItemPtr->Body;
IMailItemPtr->Body = standardText + signature
```

So first the signature has to be cached and then appended to the standard text for the body.
But here I noticed that the body is empty until set (which is logical).
But now I wonder where my signature is stored and how I can get it?

Here is the important part of my code:

```
string standardText = "Hello Outlook"
Outlook::_ApplicationPtr spOutlook(__uuidof(Outlook::Application));

// Get the MAPI namespace
Outlook::_NameSpacePtr pMAPI = spOutlook->GetNamespace("MAPI");

// Initiate a new Outlook-session
pMAPI->Logon("", "", false, true); // Log on by using the default profile or existing session (no dialog box).

// Query the MailItem interface
Outlook::_MailItemPtr IMailItemPtr = spOutlook->CreateItem(Outlook::olMailItem);


IMailItemPtr->Subject = mailSubject;
IMailItemPtr->Body = standardText.c_str();
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209091/add-signature-to-outlook-email-with-python-using-win32com

Comment: That's exactly what im looked for, thanks :)