# Why is email body, using custom template, delivered in plain text?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a list of users to send multiple attachments with custom email body (.oft template).

User's details are in an Excel file.

I had prepared (.oft template) in standard format with some images and style fonts.

When I use `msg.Send` emails are delivered with an attachment but the email body is displayed in plain text. But, `msg.Display` displays the email with an associated attachment and expected email body (.oft template).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Send_Mails()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Send_Mails")
Dim i As Integer

Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object

Set OA = CreateObject("outlook.application")
OA.Session.Logon

Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To last_row
    Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
    Set msg = OA.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Test 2\Test.oft")
    msg.To = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    msg.cc = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
    msg.Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
    
    If sh.Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then
        msg.Attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & i).Value
    End If

    msg.Display
    sh.Range("F" & i).Value = "Sent"
Next i

MsgBox "All the mails sent successfully"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `.Display` with `.Save` to see if it fixes this unusual situation.

Comment: Not Working with the .Save options. Thanks,

Comment: **If** `.Display` is a solution there **was** a trick with `.GetInspector` to get some of the functionality of `.Display`. It may have an impact. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210038/1571407.

Comment: So How can i add .GetInspector

Comment: **If** `msg.Display` follwed by `msg.send` delivers mail in correct format then try `msg.GetInspector` followed by `msg.send`. That way you do not see the flash that comes with `.Display`.

Comment: This is worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If this delivers mail in correct format

```
msg.Display
msg.send
```

try

```
msg.GetInspector
msg.send
```

That way you do not see the flash that comes with `.Display`.