# How to add a signature using pywin32?

Tags: python, html, outlook, pywin32

I am trying to add my email signature to my code, but I cannot find an updated way to send it. It is an HTML signature.

Here is the code I have:

```
mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
mailItem.Subject = Subject
mailItem.BodyFormat = 2
mailItem.HTMLBody = NewRepMessage
mailItem.To = Recipient
mailItem._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, olNS.Accounts.Item('MYEMAIL')))



mailItem.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code sets `MailItem.Account` property using late binding. I am not sure why you'd want to do that instead of just setting the property directly. That, however, won't help in any way with the signature.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210038/332059 for a discussion on how to add an Outlook signature.

Comment: Yes, I have read that discussion and it seems that method does not work anymore.

Comment: `MailItem.Display` and Redemption still work.